# Cloud Run ingress not working on certain networks

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We are live on https://whofastpass.com, I love Cloud Run, but a number of users who have reported that they cannot connect to the application using the custom domain above, https://whofastpass.com

However, when they use the service url directly, https://who-fast-pass-web-6i3erki5ca-uc.a.run.app, it works!

We are marketing the application at the moment, and I have no idea how many users are unable to reach the service using the custom domain.

I imagine this is a hard to find bug because it works on most network providers. I am certain that a firewall is not blocking connections to the service because the service url worked when used.

Are there workarounds you can propose that wont involve me loosing the SSL certificate or the cloud run service entirely?

I tried to do a packet trace, and I can see that the SYN phase of the TCP connectivity was not acknowledged.

Are there fundamental differences between custom domains and the service url that cloud run offers?

Comment: 1/2) Note: I am looking at your trace. Ping does not talk to your Cloud Run service. Ping stops at the Google Frontend (GFE) so a ping failing means the network path to Google's closest endpoint for the user has a problem and does not indicate a problem with Cloud Run. Your traces show that IP addresses are being used and do not show a DNS problem. I highly doubt that there is a problem with Google's Frontend as this is a global service that would affect many services and not just Cloud Run.

Comment: 2/2) In my opinion, you are not having a problem with Cloud Run. You have a network problem (cellular) from the user's device to Google's network. The fact that one trace is working, and another does not is coincidental and is probably not a repeatable situation. However, the level of detail required to prove this one way or another is not available in your description or the logs provided.

Comment: Are you able to reconstruct the problem? Then a google engineer can help you.

Comment: I'm inclined to think if the TCP connection doesn't go beyond SYN, something like an IP block is at play here somehow. Cloud Run probably shares some part of Google's wider IP ranges. If there are any IP-based ad blockers in the stack, that might cause it.

Comment: Also how did you configure the DNS name? Aren't you supposed to configure CNAME records for your domain (I'm not seeing any)? The other option is to configure I think 4+4 A/AAAA records, I'm only seeing 1 A record and no AAAA records for your domain name. That sounds unusual.

Comment: Are you saying you're able to reproduce this problem? Some folks on our side has checked your URL from external probes around the world and there doesn't seem to be an issue. I recommend figuring out under what circumstances it's occurring.

Comment: Right now @AhmetB-Google, going to A record, https://whofastpass.com does not seem to come up as we speak, but the CNAME www.whofastpass.com works. Is this reproduced on your end?

Comment: Update instead of using A and AAAA records, I used GoDaddy domain forwarding and things work. Why can't we just CNAME everything. Cloud Run A and AAAA records are failing me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to set up my own Frontend, with SSL, which redirects to the www CNAME record.

Something dodgy must be wrong with the way Google Frontend's A and AAAA records integrates with Cloud Run (All it had to do was point to the service).

It wasn't a real issue until I couldn't access the site anymore.

Pending when Google Cloud Run team, looks into this issue, I'd be sticking with the unconvoluted and effective approach of using my own Web Server.

Comment: This is pretty unlikely as tens of thousands other sites use the same serving stack. We’d love to investigate more if you can find out more specific details. Could your country be possibly blocking access to Google IPs?

Comment: It’s unlikely my country blocks access to all google servers. As I still use a google server but not google cloud front to do the proxying. I would be happy give an engineer access to my computer.